# when I run my jsp pgogram I got this exception error type Exception report

Tags: jsp-tags

> type Exception report
>
> message Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:
>
> An error occurred at line: 44 in the jsp file:
>   /jsp/ShoppingCart/AddBook.jsp The method getValue(String) is undefined
>   for the

type HttpServletRequest

```
   int int_BookID,int_CategoryID,int_Price,int_Quantity;
     String str_Title, str_Author, str_Publisher,str_Edition,str_Description;
            int_BookID=(int)(10000*Math.random()+1);
            int_CategoryID=Integer.parseInt(request.getValue("cat"));
            str_Title=request.getParameter("title");
            str_Author=request.getParameter("author");
            str_Publisher=request.getParameter("pub");
```

Comment: So, What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

request.getValue("cat") is the problem here. 
I suppose the 'cat' is a parameter. 
Instead , use request.getParameter("cat")

PS- I recommend you to read the basics of JSP first try the HeadFirst series.